# Blur effect in SceneKit material

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, blur, scnmaterial

Is it possible to achieve a Gaussian blur effect for a `SCNMaterial` in SceneKit? It should look like frosted glass, similar to a `UIVisualEffectView` with a `UIBlurEffectStyleLight` or `UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight` in UIKit.

Comment: This might be something comparable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999812/adding-cifilter-to-scnnode-turns-node-into-white-box/56787857#56787857