# Adding CIFilter to SCNNode turns node into white box

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'd like to add a `CIGaussianBlur` to a `SCNNode` that is being displayed in ARKit.

However, adding that filter turns the node into "a white box". Here is the node without and with filter.

**No `CIFilter`**

[image: SCNNode with no CIFilter]

**With `CIFilter`**

[image: SCNNode with CIFilter]

Here is the relevant code:

```
let gaussianBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
gaussianBlurFilter.name = "blur"

node.filters = [gaussianBlurFilter]
let material = node.geometry?.firstMaterial
material?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue

node.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.39)
camera.addChildNode(node)
```

Previous Stack Overflow questions have suggested that adding a `CIFilter` isn't possible on Metal, but I believe that is now possible as of iOS 11.

Also, I'm trying to achieve a `UIVisualEffectView`-type effect on an `SCNNode`, so if you know of another way to accomplish that please let me know!

Comment: Should you not add the filter to a layer as opposed to the node? let layer = CALayer() layer.filters = [gaussianBlurFilter]

Comment: Layer filters have never been supported on iOS. He's correct in filtering the node, which is what SceneKit supports.

Comment: any progress on this ?

Comment: @omarojo I never found a solution for this unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
let gaussianBlur    = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
gaussianBlur?.name  = "blur"
gaussianBlur?.setValue(15, forKey: "inputRadius")
node.filters        = [gaussianBlur] as? [CIFilter]
```

and configure the SceneView like so:

```
sceneView.antialiasingMode    = .none
sceneView.isJitteringEnabled  = false
```

[image]